# Angular Component: One way binding not working with object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

When passing an object from parent controller to child one way binding is not working. Its changing the parent value when child model changes. Please find below example.

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/5AJiLf?p=preview`
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking _why_ this is happening? The answer is right there in your question..."passing an object". It's the same object that you are passing a reference to. Making a change to a property of the model from the child controller is still just a change to a property of that very same object.

If this is what you're after, I'm happy to add it as an answer.

Comment: I am asking how to fix? How to isolate the scope here?

Comment: This plunkr shows an example of how you can avoid this issue. In it, I'm passing a primitive string to the child, rather than a reference to the same object.
https://plnkr.co/edit/KFC433vij7DqJhZAF9FS?p=preview